# writing rules in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am learning Prolog and would just like to check myself:
I think this question is very basic but I am just beginning.

```
father(X,Y)
mother(X,Y)
male(X)
female(X)
parent(X,Y)
diff(X,Y)
```

To write a clause for is_mother(X) is this correct?

```
is_mother(X):- female(X), parent(X,Y).
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you put in some data and tested it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
is_mother(X) :- female(X), parent(X,Y).
```

This is technically correct in that it says, *X is a mother if X is female, and X is the parent of someone (Y).* In this definition, Prolog will give you a warning about Y being a "singleton" variable since you don't use its value. To avoid that warning, you can use `_` or a name that starts with `_` to indicate a variable whose value you don't care about and Prolog won't warn that you're not using:

```
is_mother(X) :- female(X), parent(X,_).
```

The terms `female(X)` and `parent(X,_)` assume that you have either predicates `female(X)` and `parent(X,Y)` or you have facts, such as (for example) `female(sally).` where `sally` is an "atom" (a *constant* in Prolog), and/or `parent(sally, tom).`